# How to list query result in form (EntityType)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, query-builder

In my project I use data form one table (user task) to describe data to create Reservation record (reservation table).  In form I try received select list.

When run it's error :

> `Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given`

Why "array" data is wrong? What change?

#### My code:

Form:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Form;
use AppBundle\Repository\TaskRepository;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\Type\EntityType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

/**
 * Class ReservationType
 *
 * @package AppBundle\Form
 */
class ReservationType extends AbstractType
{
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
  {
    $builder
      ->add( 'taskId', EntityType::class, [
        'class' => 'AppBundle:Task',
        'query_builder' => function (TaskRepository $tr) use ($options) {
          return $tr->TaskUserListQuery( $options['userId']);
        },
        'attr' => [
          'data-type' => 'text',
          'class' => 'table-select',
          'disabled' => true
        ],
        'required' => false
      ])
    ;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver )
  {
    $resolver->setDefaults( [
                  'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Task',
                  'userId'  => null,
                ] );
  }


  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getBlockPrefix()
  {
    return 'appbundle_reservation';
  }
}
```

Repository:

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Repository;
use \Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * TaskRepository
 */
class TaskRepository extends EntityRepository
{
  /**
   * Function TaskUserListQuery
   * @return array
   */
  public function TaskUserListQuery( $userId )
  {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder( 't' )
      ->select(
        't.id',
        't.taskName'
      )
      ->orderBy( 't.id', 'ASC' )
      ->where( 't.userId = :par1' )
      ->setParameter( 'par1', $userId )
      ->getQuery()
      ->getResult();
  }
}
```

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\Reservation;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

/**
 * Reservation controller.
 *
 * @Route("/re")
 */
class ReservationController extends Controller
{

  /**
   * Creates a new reservation entity.
   *
   * @Route("/new", name="r_new")
   * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
   */
  public function newAction( Request $request )
  {
    $userId = 1;

    $reservation = new Reservation();
    $tableForm = $this->createForm( 'AppBundle\Form\ReservationType', $reservation, [
      'userId' => $userId,
    ] );
    $form = $tableForm->createView();
    $form->handleRequest( $request );

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
      $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
      $em->persist( $reservation );
      $em->flush();

      return $this->redirectToRoute( 'r_show', [ 'id' => $reservation->getId() ] );
    }

    return $this->render( 'reservation/new.html.twig', [
      'reservation'  => $reservation,
      'form'     => $form->createView(),
    ] );
  }

   // (... more)

}
```

#### When I make mistake?

I'm learn form example and  run on Symfony 3.2. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can't call `handleRequest` method on `FormView` object.

```
$tableForm = $this->createForm( 'AppBundle\Form\ReservationType',
    $reservation, ['userId' => $userId,]);
$form = $tableForm->createView(); // WTF ?
$form->handleRequest( $request );
```

TaskRepository

```
public function TaskUserListQuery( $userId )
{
    return $this->createQueryBuilder( 't' )
        ->select('t') // in this way
        ->orderBy( 't.id', 'ASC' )
        ->where( 't.userId = :par1' )
        ->setParameter( 'par1', $userId );
}
```

In your case when you are using selecting ('t.id', ...)
QueryBuilder will return plain array

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:2 [▼
    "id" => 1
    "task_name" => "New Task"
  ]
]
```

but `EntityType` expects an array of objects like

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => Task {#448 ▶}
]
```

Finally, dont forget add option `'choice_label' => 'task_name'` in `buildForm` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should return a querybuilder object instance instead of result for the query_builder parameter as [described in the doc here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#query-builder). So change your repo method as follow:

```
  /**
   * Function TaskUserListQuery
   * @return QueryBuilder
   */
  public function TaskUserListQuery( $userId )
  {
    return $this->createQueryBuilder( 't' )
      ->select(
        't.id',
        't.taskName'
      )
      ->orderBy( 't.id', 'ASC' )
      ->where( 't.userId = :par1' )
      ->setParameter( 'par1', $userId );
  }
```

Hope this help

Comment: I replace it with `@return QueryBuilder` and still return an error: Expected argument of type "Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder", "array" given

Comment: @user23123 changing only the docblock will not change what your code returns. Take a better look to Matteo's answer that is right.

Comment: hi @user23123 I also change the return value of the method, look at the answer's code, probably you should change the argument in the select method, probably it need for the whole object. Let me know